# Is there a way to make the discord bot reply to someone's dm that it is prohibited to send private messages?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my discord bot to send something like "Youre not allowed to send messages here" whenever someone DMs it

Here is what I have so far:

```
if(message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel){
   return;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you can either reply to the message or send a message in the same channel as the message (DM channel)

```js
if(message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel && !message.author.bot) {
  return message.reply('You can not message me through DMs')
}
```

Or

```js
if(message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel && !message.author.bot) {
  return message.channel.send('You can not message me through DMs')
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but it seems like it's doing a loop of its own. The messages seem to repeat in an endless loop. Any clue on why that's happening?

Comment: you just need to make sure it doesn't respond to bot messages, I suggest you put `if (message.author.bot) return` at the top of your `message` event. but for the purpose of this question, I edited my answer accordingly